# Writing a couchdb design document

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

**Would anyone be willing to provide a full documentation example on how to write a couchdb design document?**

I've never been able to find a proper documentation on that. I'm able to find a list of the available methods, but not how to write them in the design document.
For example, the [couchdb documentation in this page](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/ddocs.html#view-functions) explains how to use a map function, but it doesn't explain that this function is implemented in the design document the following way:

```
{
  "views": {
    "someView": {
      "map": "function(doc){ emit(doc.name, doc) }"
    }
  }
}
```

There are very sparse information on that in [this page](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/json-structure.html#design-document) but it seems very incomplete to me. For example it doesn't even mention there can be "validate_doc_update" in the structure.

I think a good documentation example would be very useful in the couchdb doc itself in fact.
It could look like the following:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/exampleDesignDocument",
  "_rev": "1-11111111111111111111111111",
  "views": {
    "someView": {
      "map": "function(doc){ emit(doc.name, doc) }",
      ...
    }
  },
  "lists": {
    "someList": "function(head, req){ send('<html>hello</html>') }"
  }
  ...
}
```

This example would display usages of **all design documents methods** including (but not limited to if I forgot some): **view (map, reduce functions...), show, list, update, filter, validate**.

Comment: IBM Cloudant has a good documentation section https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/design_documents.html#design-documents

Comment: I don't know why this has been voted down. It is a serious question and there are very few examples available through the documentation or a Google search that demonstrate the implementation of update handlers. Update handlers do not even SHOW UP in the Fauxton utility of CouchDB 2.2.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#filtered-changes) docs provide good documentation elements to answer, as well as [IBM cloudant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/design_documents.html#design-documents), as proposed by @xpqz.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/exampleDesignDocument",
  "_rev": "1-11111111111111111111111111",
  "views": {
    "someView": {
      "map": "function(doc){ emit(doc.name, doc) }",
      ...
    }
  },
  "shows": {
    "someShowFunction": "function (doc, req) { ... }"
  },
  "lists": {
    "someList": "function(head, req){ send('<html>hello</html>') }"
  },
  "updates": {
    "oneUpdateFunc": "function (doc, req) { ... }"
  },
  "filters": {
    "someFilter": "function(doc, req){ if (doc.owner === req.userCtx.name) return true; else return false }"
  },
  "validate_doc_update": "function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj) { ... }"
}
```

But this answer can still be improved and completed I think.